# GridView Getting Out of Range Exception

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a program that watches the text files in a network path folder whenever a text file is created it will be displayed on a Gridview as a path "@\192.168.10.5\Export" + the file name and after that it will loop through the Gridview then perform a insert query to database, if one text file is created, it works just fine, but if two text files are created, i'm getting Getting Out of Range Exception, which means it won't process the second text file, i don't know why?

Comment: The deleting of the entire code is IMHO bad idea. Now nobody can see what is pointed out in the answer and he cannot learn anything, if he find this question

Comment: i'm sorry, i just realized the code exposes some sensitive information in my side, i will return it as soon as i can after i edit some few parts.

Comment: In that case you should maybe contact moderators to delete it permanently, because it can still be seen in revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right:

- The first foreach loop is considered to go through all rows
- The second loop (`for ... i < pathGrid.Rows.Count ...`) should go through all cells in one row?

Why do you use row index as parameter in second loop, if you use it as cell index in `rows.Cells[i]` ?

I think here is the issue.

**EDIT:**

To explain my thought:

I don't know your datagrid structure, but i assume, each row contains the file path in first cell. So use only the first loop:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in pathGrid.Rows){
    string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(rows.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
.
.
.
```

Comment: yes i think u're right, the first loop goes through all the rows, then the second loop is wrong, i need a proper loop to read the values of the cells.

Comment: Added edit to explait it better. Maybe the exact structure of your datagrid will help to understand it.